# IIS Request Hanging for single AJAX request at AquireRequestState stage

Tags: asp.net, .net, oracle, iis, odbc

We have a AngularJS application talking to a .NET webforms backend; it does a bunch of AJAX requests to a number of systems and amalgamates lots of information into a single page to make it faster for users.    The page loads very quickly, but there is a single AJAX request (GetPatientRadiology) that *sometimes* seems to be hanging - i.e. if I go into View Current Requests in the AppPool, I see it sitting there in the AquireRequestState.

The memory for the AppPool remains low (usual behaviour), however when this happens, the CPU usage for the AppPool jumps to about 30% (unusual for this app).   It remains like this until I recycle the appPool, for some reason it never seems to timeout - we've observed it going for more than 17 hours.

The application serves up this page (and therefore makes the GetPatientRadiology request) around 22,000 times a day, and this seems to happen < 10 times per day.   The request is a single query to an Oracle database that returns in < 0.1seconds in SQL Developer.   There are multiple other queries to the same ConnectionString and there are no issues with those.

It's running on a Windows 2008R2 server (IIS7.5), and ASP.NET 4.6.1.   Yes, I know it's old... but we're stuck with some legacy equipment :(

I've cast about and read dozens of articles, but can't see anything that helps specifically; there have been suggestions to use MS Debug Diags which I've done and captured the process when it's happening in production; below is an extract from it, but I don't know where to start interpreting it, and am hoping for some help.

Top 5 Threads by CPU time

````
Thread ID: 44     Total CPU Time: 00:00:07.222     Entry Point for Thread: clr!StrongNameFreeBuffer+35dc0 
Thread ID: 3     Total CPU Time: 00:00:06.972     Entry Point for Thread: w3tp+2040 
Thread ID: 46     Total CPU Time: 00:00:06.145     Entry Point for Thread: clr!StrongNameFreeBuffer+35dc0 
Thread ID: 5     Total CPU Time: 00:00:05.911     Entry Point for Thread: w3tp+2040 ```

Thread 43 - System ID 5224

Entry point   clr!StrongNameFreeBuffer+35dc0 
Create time   8/11/2019 11:22:24 a.m. 
Time spent in user mode   0 Days 00:05:02.595 
Time spent in kernel mode   0 Days 00:05:06.853 


This thread is not fully resolved and may or may not be a problem. Further analysis of these threads may be required.


.NET Call Stack


System_Data_ni!DomainNeutralILStubClass.IL_STUB_PInvoke(System.Data.Odbc.OdbcStatementHandle, UInt16, SQL_C, System.Data.Odbc.CNativeBuffer, IntPtr, IntPtr ByRef)+e8 
[[InlinedCallFrame] (System.Data.Common.UnsafeNativeMethods.SQLGetData)] System.Data.Common.UnsafeNativeMethods.SQLGetData(System.Data.Odbc.OdbcStatementHandle, UInt16, SQL_C, System.Data.Odbc.CNativeBuffer, IntPtr, IntPtrByRef) 
System_Data_ni!System.Data.Odbc.OdbcStatementHandle.GetData(Int32, SQL_C, System.Data.Odbc.CNativeBuffer, Int32, IntPtr ByRef)+30 
System_Data_ni!System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.GetData(Int32, SQL_C, Int32, Int32 ByRef)+74 
System_Data_ni!System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.internalGetString(Int32)+1d4 
System_Data_ni!System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.GetValue(Int32, System.Data.Odbc.TypeMap)+73 
System_Data_ni!System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.GetValue(Int32)+43 
_Default.GetPatientRadiology(System.String)+330 
[[DebuggerU2MCatchHandlerFrame]] 
[[HelperMethodFrame_PROTECTOBJ] (System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod)] System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(System.Object, System.Object[], System.Signature, Boolean) 
mscorlib_ni!System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(System.Object, System.Object[], System.Object[])+80 
mscorlib_ni!System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(System.Object, System.Reflection.BindingFlags, System.Reflection.Binder, System.Object[], System.Globalization.CultureInfo)+8e 
System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethod(System.Object, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2)+139 
System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.InvokeMethod(System.Web.HttpContext, System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2)+74 
System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(System.Web.HttpContext, System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData)+5d 
System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule.OnPostAcquireRequestState(System.Object, System.EventArgs)+120 
System_Web_ni!System.Web.HttpApplication+SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()+8b 
System_Web_ni!System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep)+c3 
System_Web_ni!System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep, Boolean ByRef)+58 
System_Web_ni!System.Web.HttpApplication+PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(System.Exception)+5bc 
System_Web_ni!System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(System.Web.HttpContext, System.AsyncCallback)+79 
System_Web_ni!System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest, System.Web.HttpContext)+1db 
System_Web_ni!System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr, IntPtr, IntPtr, Int32)+3cd 
System_Web_ni!System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr, IntPtr, IntPtr, Int32)+13 
System_Web_ni!DomainNeutralILStubClass.IL_STUB_ReversePInvoke(Int64, Int64, Int64, Int32)+52 
System_Web_ni!DomainNeutralILStubClass.IL_STUB_PInvoke(IntPtr, System.Web.RequestNotificationStatus ByRef)+7e 
[[InlinedCallFrame] (System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion)] System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr, System.Web.RequestNotificationStatusByRef) 
System_Web_ni!System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr, IntPtr, IntPtr, Int32)+595 
System_Web_ni!System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr, IntPtr, IntPtr, Int32)+13 
System_Web_ni!DomainNeutralILStubClass.IL_STUB_ReversePInvoke(Int64, Int64, Int64, Int32)+52 
[[ContextTransitionFrame]] 

Full Call Stack


ntdll!NtSetEvent+a 
KERNELBASE!SetEvent+c 
sqora32+17a3 
sqora32!SQLGetData+175 
odbc32!SQLGetData+897 
System_Data_ni!DomainNeutralILStubClass.IL_STUB_PInvoke(System.Data.Odbc.OdbcStatementHandle, UInt16, SQL_C, System.Data.Odbc.CNativeBuffer, IntPtr, IntPtr ByRef)+e8 
[[InlinedCallFrame] (System.Data.Common.UnsafeNativeMethods.SQLGetData)] System.Data.Common.UnsafeNativeMethods.SQLGetData(System.Data.Odbc.OdbcStatementHandle, UInt16, SQL_C, System.Data.Odbc.CNativeBuffer, IntPtr, IntPtrByRef) 
System_Data_ni!System.Data.Odbc.OdbcStatementHandle.GetData(Int32, SQL_C, System.Data.Odbc.CNativeBuffer, Int32, IntPtr ByRef)+30 
System_Data_ni!System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.GetData(Int32, SQL_C, Int32, Int32 ByRef)+74 
System_Data_ni!System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.internalGetString(Int32)+1d4 
System_Data_ni!System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.GetValue(Int32, System.Data.Odbc.TypeMap)+73 
System_Data_ni!System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.GetValue(Int32)+43 
_Default.GetPatientRadiology(System.String)+330 
clr!LogHelp_LogAssert+2043 
clr!LogHelp_LogAssert+1ef8 
clr!DllUnregisterServerInternal+60f46 
clr!DllUnregisterServerInternal+613ff 
[[DebuggerU2MCatchHandlerFrame]] 
[[HelperMethodFrame_PROTECTOBJ] (System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod)] System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(System.Object, System.Object[], System.Signature, Boolean) 
mscorlib_ni!System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(System.Object, System.Object[], System.Object[])+80 
mscorlib_ni!System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(System.Object, System.Reflection.BindingFlags, System.Reflection.Binder, System.Object[], System.Globalization.CultureInfo)+8e 
System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethod(System.Object, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2<System.String,System.Object>)+139 
System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.InvokeMethod(System.Web.HttpContext, System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2<System.String,System.Object>)+74 
System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(System.Web.HttpContext, System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData)+5d 
System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule.OnPostAcquireRequestState(System.Object, System.EventArgs)+120 
System_Web_ni!System.Web.HttpApplication+SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()+8b 
System_Web_ni!System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep)+c3 
System_Web_ni!System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep, Boolean ByRef)+58 
System_Web_ni!System.Web.HttpApplication+PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(System.Exception)+5bc 
System_Web_ni!System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(System.Web.HttpContext, System.AsyncCallback)+79 
System_Web_ni!System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest, System.Web.HttpContext)+1db 
System_Web_ni!System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr, IntPtr, IntPtr, Int32)+3cd 
System_Web_ni!System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr, IntPtr, IntPtr, Int32)+13 
System_Web_ni!DomainNeutralILStubClass.IL_STUB_ReversePInvoke(Int64, Int64, Int64, Int32)+52 
clr+21fe 
webengine4!PerfDecrementGlobalCounter+33f 
webengine4!RegisterModule+3cca 
webengine4!PerfDecrementGlobalCounter+fb 
webengine4!MgdWebSocketWriteFragment+36f 
iiscore+2e48 
iiscore+46a4 
iiscore+a775 
iiscore+1ee5 
iiscore+a81c 
webengine4!STRU::Unescape+501 
webengine4!MgdIndicateCompletion+22 
System_Web_ni!DomainNeutralILStubClass.IL_STUB_PInvoke(IntPtr, System.Web.RequestNotificationStatus ByRef)+7e 
[[InlinedCallFrame] (System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion)] System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr, System.Web.RequestNotificationStatusByRef) 
System_Web_ni!System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr, IntPtr, IntPtr, Int32)+595 
System_Web_ni!System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr, IntPtr, IntPtr, Int32)+13 
System_Web_ni!DomainNeutralILStubClass.IL_STUB_ReversePInvoke(Int64, Int64, Int64, Int32)+52 
clr+2453 
clr!DllUnregisterServerInternal+4cb3a 
clr!LogHelp_LogAssert+5ca4 
[[ContextTransitionFrame]] 
clr!DllUnregisterServerInternal+4cbe5 
clr+23fd 
webengine4!PerfDecrementGlobalCounter+33f 
webengine4!PerfDecrementGlobalCounter+292 
clr!LogHelp_LogAssert+49ff 
clr!LogHelp_LogAssert+35fc 
clr!LogHelp_LogAssert+33a5 
clr!StrongNameFreeBuffer+35e3f 
kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+d 
ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+1d
````

[AppPool Current Requests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHSeG.png)

Many thanks,

David

Comment: The call stack seems to indicate that this app uses Oracle database for sessions. That's really rare and can be troublesome. You need the original developers to help.

Comment: By viewing the stack trace, we would know IIS is trying to get data from Oracle database. And the code has already gone into native code. So it is hard to digging further from here. It is recommended to contact the vendor of oracle data access driver. Because only they know in which condition, the method would hang. Another way to troubleshooting this issue is make some change and monitor its effect.